# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9300: Connexion refusée

Tags: elasticsearch, port

I am trying to connect nuxeo to elasticsearch 6 with port 9300, but the connection is refused.
When I run the `curl -XGET 'localhost: 9300'`  command,

I got the error message:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9300: Connection refused.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: you should use 9200 port instead of 9300

Comment: I need port 9300 to communicate nuxeo and ES

Answer (score 0):

try it , elastic uses 9200 port for API gateway

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```

Comment: It works well with curl  http: // localhost: 9200